# Resolvendo promise no angular

Tags: typescript, ionic3, angular-5

Estou trabalhando em uma aplicação com Ionic 3 + Angular 5 e tenho que pegar um valor do storage do Ionic da seguinte forma:

```
 this.userStorageService.get('expiresIn')
            .then((data) => this.tokenExpirationTimeFromApi = data);
 console.log(this.tokenExpirationTimeFromApi);
```

No entanto quando faço o console.log fora da promisse é retornado 'undefined', mas se eu colocar o console.log dentro do .then ele retorna normal. Ai eu fiz um setTimeOut:

```
this.userStorageService.get('expiresIn')
        .then((data) => this.tokenExpirationTimeFromApi = data);
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(this.tokenExpirationTimeFromApi);
    },1000);
```

Dessa forma funciona, mas acho que não é o certo a se fazer. Como que faço pra ter o valor do retorno da promisse e só a partir daí continuar o fluxo da aplicação? Help, please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, o que ocorre é que um `Promise` executa de forma *assíncrona*, ou seja, quando você printa o `console.log` na próxima linha fora do `then()` o valor ainda não foi recuperado do storage. O valor é recuperado corretamente, somente não no momento que você espera que seja, já que está misturando código *síncrono* com
*assíncrono*.

> Para esclarecer mais sobre o funcionamento dos Promises dê uma lida na
>   [documentação da mozilla.](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

PS: Talvez se você postar mais detalhes do seu código seja possível auxiliar em uma forma de proceder.

PS2: A forma de trabalhar com `Promises` é um pouco diferente do habitual quando você programa de forma mais "procedural". Uma possibilidade para o seu código (não sabendo realmente o que você deseja fazer) seria retornar o resultado no `then` para um proximo `callback` e continuar o processamento.

---

Segue um exemplo um pouco mais elaborado desta vez, aqui eu simulei um `Storage` que retorna um promise para um `Provider`, que processa essa informação e encaminha um `Promise` com esse valor *já processado* para o `Controller` que então utiliza um callback, *que não é exatamente necessário* para atualizar a `View`.

```js
class Storage {
  constructor() {
    this.data = Math.random() * 10;
  }
  
  getData() {
    console.log("Buscando dados no storage..")
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      // simula um tempo indeterminado para tarefa completar
      setTimeout(() => resolve(this.data), Math.random() * 3000);
    });
  }
}

class MyStorageProvider{
  constructor() {
    this.storage = new Storage();
  }
  
  fetchStorageData() {
    console.log("Chamando storage para pegar dados..");
    return this.storage.getData()
        .then(data => {
      console.log("Dados recuperados... verificando.");
      return data > 5;
    });
  }
}

class MyController {
  constructor() {
    this.output = document.querySelector('#output');
    this.provider = new MyStorageProvider();
  }
  
  requestDataFromStorage() {
    this.provider.fetchStorageData()
      // chamando o callback assim evita perder o escopo.
      // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34930771/why-is-this-undefined-inside-class-method-when-using-promises
      .then(data => this.handleStorageData(data));
  }
  
  handleStorageData(data) {
    console.log("Processando dados para visão.. ");
    this.output.innerHTML = data;
  } 
}

var controller = new MyController();
controller.requestDataFromStorage();
```

```html
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Eu simplesmente quero pegar esse expirationIn para depois poder fazer uma validação com o horário atual. Tipo:

Comment: this.currentTime = new Date().getTime();
this.tokenExpirationTime = new Date(this.tokenExpirationTimeFromApi).getTime();
return this.currentTime > this.tokenExpirationTime;

Comment: Vou tentar dessa forma que você mostrou...

Comment: Não deu certo, o problema é que eu preciso retornar um boolean para a chamada desse método, tipo falando se o horário atual é maior que o do expirationIn. Fiz utilizando o callback, mas continua retornando undefined.

Comment: da uma olhada se o outro exemplo te ajuda.

Comment: Não deu certo. É o seguinte, eu preciso pegar esse valor fora do then entende, pois preciso fazer o retorno do método como um boolean. Pesquisei em milhões de lugares, mas ninguém conseguiu me explicar ao certo... Acho que não tem como fazer

Comment: Cara, a chamada do método é assíncrono. Vc pode retornar um promise com um boolean como valor e tratar fora. N tenho como te dar um exemplo com angular agora. Mas assim q puder eu atualizo a resposta. Tbm da pra usar um callback. Vou tentar montar um exemplo dos dois casos pra vc ver depois..

Comment: @FellipeBotelho Atualizei a respostar com um exemplo mais completo, talvez esclareça como você pode trabalhar com chamadas assincronas.